# Sphinx calculation issue with large numbers

Tags: sphinx

I have connected mysql client with sphinx server
when I issue this query

`select 20130919.0+(15/4),15/4  from [INDEX] limit 1;`
I get the following result

```
+------+--------+-------------------+----------+
| id   | weight | 20130919.0+(15/4) | 15/4     |
+------+--------+-------------------+----------+
| 7414 |      1 |   20130924.000000 | 3.750000 |
+------+--------+-------------------+----------+
```

Note that `15/4` returns 3.75 but when it is added to `20130919.0` it returns wrong result.

in another case when i write the following query

`select 2222+15/4,15/4  from [INDEX] limit 1;`

It returns correct result.

```
+------+--------+-------------+----------+
| id   | weight | 2222+15/4   | 15/4     |
+------+--------+-------------+----------+
| 7414 |      1 | 2225.750000 | 3.750000 |
+------+--------+-------------+----------+
```

similarly in the previous case third column should have the value `20130922.75`. I thought the problem was that sphinx return rounded off number but in that case it should have been `20130923.000` not `20130924.000`.

What I want is that it should return a correct floating point number but it is acting strangely. Hope someone here has any explanation for this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sphinx mostly does single precision float maths

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

which only uses 8 bits for the exponent. The amount of decimal digits that can be stored precisely is approximately 7 - you have 8.

There is a double() function, but I havent tested it.

---

Edit: Actully no, double() wont help.

```
sphinxQL>select double(20130919.0)+(15/4),15/4  from sample2 limit 1;
+---------------------------+----------+
| double(20130919.0)+(15/4) | 15/4     |
+---------------------------+----------+
|           20130924.000000 | 3.750000 |
+---------------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

sphinxQL>select double(20130919.0+(15/4)),15/4  from sample2 limit 1;
+---------------------------+----------+
| double(20130919.0+(15/4)) | 15/4     |
+---------------------------+----------+
|           20130924.000000 | 3.750000 |
+---------------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: yeah your are right. I read this here http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.2.1/operators.html#expr-ari-ops and i know about the double function but the problem is that we are using Sphinx 2.0.11 but it is available in 2.2.1-beta. is there any work around for that ?

Comment: It appears there is no workaround as such for floats. Stuck with single percision. But maybe what ever you are trying to do, can be rewritten to avoid floating point numbers altogether, dont know.